# Importing materials from blender to UE4

Tags: blender, materials, unreal-4, unreal

So my problem is that I have a nice green glass material in blender which I imported to UE4 (4.8.1) but in the editor the material was just a simple green colour.

I have no idea what I should do to fix this problem.

I appreciate any help. If you need any more details or pictures, let me know.

Thank you

Glass in blender:
[image]

Material in blender:
[image]

Glass in UE4:
[image]
Material in UE4:[image]

Comment: Adding pictures when you have a visual-related bug is always a good idea :)

Comment: So the point is that while in theory (or at least I thought) you can import materials to UE4, in practice it only imported the base colour of the original material and nothing else

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a transparent material you have to make your material "translucent". Glass also has the property that its surface is very shiny, so you also have to change the "Translucency Lighting Mode" to "Surface", otherwise you can not control highlights on the surface.

Be sure to adjust the "Opacity" output pin of your material. You can have a look [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Rendering/Materials/HowTo/Transparency/index.html) for more information.

[image]